# Subquery a number within a range

Tags: sql

I'm trying to query the transactions made by an `ID_NUMBER` in `TBL_TRANSACTIONS`
and the requirement is to make sure that the `ID_NUMBER` is existing in `TBL_ID_NUMBER`.

```
SELECT *
FROM TBL_TRANSACTIONS
WHERE ID_NUMBER IN ( SELECT ??????
                     FROM TBL_ID_NUMBER)
```

The problem is the ID numbers are in range e.g. `10-50`, `51-90`, `91-100`
Is there a way I can query the number between this two columns? Let's say `ID_NUMBER` is 19?

```
TBL_ID_NUMBER (table)
ID_FROM (column1)   ID_TO (column2)
10                  50
```

Comment: case when id between 10 and 50 then ... when id between 51 and 90 then ... end

Comment: Please post your data structure with data in it please and an expected output

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if U ment this but heres a suggestion ;)

```
    SELECT *
FROM TBL_TRANSACTIONS
WHERE ID_NUMBER >= ( SELECT ID_FROM
                     FROM TBL_ID_NUMBER
                     WHERE 
                     ID_NUMBER = 19)
AND ID_NUMBER <= ( SELECT ID_FROM
                     FROM TBL_ID_NUMBER
                     WHERE 
                     ID_NUMBER = 19)
```

> EDIT: I dont know your db structure so here is an other suggestion

```
SELECT *
    FROM TBL_TRANSACTIONS
    WHERE ID_NUMBER >= ( SELECT ID_FROM
                         FROM TBL_ID_NUMBER
                         WHERE 
                           ID_FROM <= 19
                         AND 
                           ID_TO >= 19)
    AND ID_NUMBER <= ( SELECT ID_TO
                         FROM TBL_ID_NUMBER
                         WHERE 
                           ID_FROM <= 19
                         AND 
                           ID_TO >= 19)
```